# Why can't I use the 14.10 development apis?

Tags: 14.04, application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

So I am developing an Ubuntu Touch app and I am running the devel (utopic) channel on my phone, but 14.04 on my PC. I've changed the manifest to use the 14.10 framework, but when I run it on my phone nothing happens as it's supposed to:

I have this code from the Page example on developer.ubuntu.com

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1
MainView {
    width: units.gu(48)
    height: units.gu(60)
    Page {
        title: i18n.tr("Example page")
        Label {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: i18n.tr("Hello world!")
        }
        head.actions: [
            Action {
                iconName: "add"
                text: i18n.tr("Search")
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

There's no icon in the header and I am guessing this is the framework's fault. What do I do?

**Note**: I changed the iconName from search to add just to test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the useDeprecatedToolbar property of your MainView to false.

This is temporary because we are currently supporting an old API (tools for toolbar), and a new (actions to go in the header). For Ubuntu.Components 1.1, the default value of useDeprecatedToolbar, which is now true, will be changed to false in the very near future (this week or the next).

Comment: Wow, awesome. I'm such a klutz. I read about this, but I thought it would do the exact opposite.

Comment: Also, do you happen to know how I can create a new page like in the contacts app, by swiping from the bottom and a close button on top. Is it a panel?

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question, that way the answer will be easily discoverable by other people too, instead of being buried here in comments